# How to fully navigate google sheets menu with selenium

Tags: selenium, google-sheets

[image: menu]

I have succeeded in opening the "Add-ons" menu but I am unable to find any reference to the "email spreadsheet" and further "create rule" in the page source. I am unable to find anything online detailing whether it is possible to traverse the full menu in this way using selenium. Can anyone confirm that it is? How would I do it? What should I be looking for?

Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Here xpath locator how you can get any sub menu:

```
//div[contains(@class,'apps-menuitem') and .='Create Rule']
```

You can also check if menu is enable by `goog-menuitem-disabled` class.

Comment: I tried everything but did not seem to get that to work. I am trying a different route entirely. Thanks!